# How to disable numbers completion in kite copilot for python?

Tags: python

I'm loving the Kite copilot, but the fact they try to autocomplete numbers is disruptive.
Any workarounds to prevent this?

[image: screenshot of for example - i write two and have twenty suggested to me]

Comment: Yes!  I don't understand why its trying to guess numbers.  The odds of a useful guess are extremely low.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I found was to turn off "show completions on the fly" (in Spyder)
I then have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger the autocompletes, but it's better than the alternative.